# Codeigniter session generates new session on every page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, session-cookies

On every page I see that new session is generated with null userdata

**On model constructor**

```
$this->config->set_item('sess_table_name', 'xx_sessions');
```

Because I want to store this session in another table because the other session table is being used for another login activity

**Login function**

```
function login($username,$password)
{

    $this->db->where('login',$username);
    $this->db->where('pass',$password);
    $q=$this->db->get('prof');
    // print $this->db->last_query();

    if($this->db->count_all_results())
    {
        $arr=$q->row();

        // creating the session 
        $this->session->set_userdata('login',$arr->id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('prof',$arr->profile_id);
        // print_r( $arr);
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

This login function is on a model. After login and generating the session the page redirects to another page, on that page I see the session builds without any problem but when I move to another page the session losses along with the userdata.

**I use the following function to check session data**

```
function print_session()
    {
        print_r( $this->session->all_userdata());
    }
```

Where I'm wrong ? Tank_auth library and ion_auth library works fine .. I had already used the

Comment: have you auto loaded the session library?

Comment: @shuvo I load session library in model constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `session` library name into the autoloader configuration, in `application/config/autoload.php:`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Then it's available automatically in each controller and everywhere in your application and you get your session data from anywhere:

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

And if you don't want to auto load session library then you have to initialize the Session class manually in your controller constructor, use the `$this->load->library` function:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

For details have a look here:http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

Edit **/application/config/config.php** and set cookie domain variable

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".yourdomain.com";
```

It will work!

*.yourdomain.com makes the cookie available throughout the domain and its sub-domains.*

Answer (score 0):

I have met same problem, and i have searched lots of pages.
I figured out that changing sess_cookie_name solves the problem(new sessions generating issue)

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'somenewname'